# Pass json through click event to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-1.7

I have this old "closed" system where it runs IE in its own container, meaning I have to code like a caveman in many cases because I can't use any browser developer tools/console to x-ray the objects being returned from the remote system.

Now, the specific function I'm looking at is a callback from a third party (it gets complicated) that returns what I am willing to bet is a standard JSON object.

```
function core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate(dataType, oData)
{
    if (dataType == "Units")
    {
        // Bail if dispatch report xml hasn't been loaded yet.
        if (oXml == null)
            return;

        ..... does lots of stuff

        // Reload the content in case any of our displayed units changed
        processUeDelta.click();
    }
}

... at the bottom of the page

<button style="display:none;" type="button" id="processUeDelta"/>
```

and the attached javascript file that I was hoping would use jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#processUeDelta").click(function(){
        var i = 0;
        alert(this.ueDelta);
        for(var propertyName in this.ueDelta)
        {
            i++;
            alert("property " + i + ": " + oData[propertyName]);
        }
    });
});
```

Now, currently the last function that binds itself to the hidden button cannot parse oData. I'm stuck on two things here.

1. I'm not sure *how* to pass the oData object to the attached eventhandler
2. I'm not too keen on this design, perhaps there is another way were I can take out the intermediary button so I can then process the JSON data object oData.

Points of note:

- This is based on a data pump, so this callback is being called on an average of 5s.
- I am limited to using jQuery 1.7.1
- I cannot see the object, my browser cannot act as a test harness, there are too many moving parts for me to be able to test it from outside the application.

Comment: Are you not able to edit the `core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate` function?

Comment: @NaNpx that is where I'm playing. If you can see a way to this that I'm not seeing, please, enlighten me

Comment: If you can update `core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate` then why trigger an event on the hidden button to pass the data?  You can just create a function in your jQuery file and call it from `core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate` passing in `oData` as a parameter.

Comment: @NaNpx I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  My issue with core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate is that it is in a different part of the webapp (literally up the stack, closer to the root).  So it is the base callback function for many other functions that subscribe to it.  Hence, I cannot edit it directly purely for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate` function with your own and then call the original `core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate` function.  In your jQuery file do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window._core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate = core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate;

    window.core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate = function(dataType, oData){

        // pass the parameters into the original function
        _core_OnUeDeltaItemsUpdate(dataType, oData);

        // do whatever you need to do with oData
        var i = 0;
        alert(this.ueDelta);
        for(var propertyName in this.ueDelta)
        {
            i++;
            alert("property " + i + ": " + oData[propertyName]);
        }
    }
});
```